# Debug JsonConvert.SerializeObject and object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, json.net, nullreferenceexception

I cant seem to figure out why the method "sometimes" cause this null reference exception. I run the code on my localhost and it works fine when this appears for some users.   When I restart the site it also goes away on the server.

My question is how can I debug this?  Its taking a .NET object and trying to serialize it but I cant tell which property is causing this issue.

Method

```
 public static string ToJSON(this object o)
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(o, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
               ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
            });
        }
```

Exception

```
     at System.Text.StringBuilder.Append(Char value)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter.WriteEnd(JsonToken token)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.AutoCompleteClose(JsonContainerType type)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteEndObject()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.WriteEnd(JsonContainerType type)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.AutoCompleteAll()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter.Close()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonWriter.System.IDisposable.Dispose()
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObjectInternal(Object value, Type type, JsonSerializer jsonSerializer)
   at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Object value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
   at Tournaments.Common.Extensions.ObjectExtensions.ToJSON(Object o)
```

**Try/Catch**

I tried the below and the JavascriptSerializer throws the error  `A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'Tournaments.Models.Events.EventModel'.`  However I dont know what object has this EventModel, which could be multiple.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        @{ 

            string model = null;
            try
            {
                model = Model.Designer.ToJSON();
            }
            catch (Exception ex )
            {
                model = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(Model.Designer);
            }
            }
            app.viewModel.members.bracket.init(@Html.Raw(model));
    </script>
```

Comment: What kind of object is `o` that you are serializing and what is its value?  You should log out this information to get clues on what is going wrong.

Comment: A lot of properties and lists of complex objects

Comment: Logging is a good approach - even add a try/catch inside ToJSON() and set a breakpoint on the catch; seeing an example of the object causing the problem would be helpful, even if there are others also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was able to narrow it down by using ToJSON on the complex properties.  For some reason entity framework is storing a child list on the property in cache when it shouldn’t at all as the query never pulls it before storing in cache. I basically told automapper to ignore those properties on map.

Comment: Nice, any code to back it up for people in the future?

Answer (score 1):

The object `o` has a property that is a reference to itself and JSON Serialization doesn't support circular references.

You could decorate your `o` object properties with [JsonIgnore Attribute](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm)'s, or create a another class without the property or if you need the hierarchy use a different object that's not going to cause a circular reference.

If it's an ambiguous case, logging will probably be the quickest way to track down the offending object.

Answer (score 0):

I usually like working with the Json options just to deal with this

The options I like

```
static readonly JsonSerializerSettings _json = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    Error = OnJsonError,
    DateFormatHandling = DateFormatHandling.IsoDateFormat,
    MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore,
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,
    ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor,
};
```

This is my error handler:

```
private static void OnJsonError(object? sender, 
Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.ErrorEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CurrentObject is null)
    {

        _logger?.LogWarning("Serialization on {path} generated an exception {Error} with warning {Message}"
            , e.ErrorContext.Path
            , e.ErrorContext.Error.GetType().Name
            , e.ErrorContext.Error.Message
            );
    }
    else
    {
        _logger?.LogWarning("Serialization on {Name} had issues with path {Path} and generated an exception {Error} with warning {Message}"
            , e.CurrentObject.GetType().Name
            , e.ErrorContext.Path
            , e.ErrorContext.Error.GetType().Name
            , e.ErrorContext.Error.Message
            );
    }
    
    e.ErrorContext.Handled = true;

}
```

If you have an error it will print out the property that failed to load.
Depending on the use case you can "fix" it of fail it.